# Find out commit id of branch before I pulled

Tags: git, branch

I am working in a git repository on the master branch. Recently I have pulled from a remote to update the branch.
Is there some way to find out, which commit-ID was the HEAD of master before I pulled?

Comment: Run `git reflog master` and you'll find some clues.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @ElpieKay. Post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git reflog` solved my problem, as suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158107/find-out-commit-id-of-branch-before-i-pulled#comment67585057_40158107) by @ElpieKay

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer. From the git documentation: 'Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the local repository.'. You'll even see "pull: Fast-forward".

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't merge anything after the pull you can use

```
git log -1 --merges
```

This will print the latest merge commit with format

```
commit <merge-commit-hash>
Merge: <first-parent-hash> <second-parent-hash> ...
Author: ...
Date: ...
```

The second line (the one that starts with "Merge") lists the parents of that merge commit. The first one (`<first-parent-hash>`) is the hash of the commit HEAD was pointing to before you merged.

In other words, you had `<first-parent-hash>` checked out when you typed `git pull`.

**EDIT**
Limitation: As [jacob-krall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3140/jacob-krall) pointed out, this won't show you where `HEAD` was if the `merge` (that was performed as part of the `pull`) resolved as a fast-forward since such merges don't create commit objects.

Comment: No. By default git does not create a new commit object when doing a fast forward merge. It just fast forwards the master pointer to the commit the merged branch is pointing to. Since git log is used to show commits, fast forward merges are not reflected in the output.

Comment: Then I think it does not answer the question, which is "what was `HEAD` before I pulled?", not "what was `HEAD` before I merged?"

Comment: `git pull` is just a shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD` (see [git-pull doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). But you are right .. git log won't tell you about fast forward merges.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple cases where you've not changed your branch after the pull, you could use the `master@{1}` or `main@{1}` reference, e.g. `git log -1 master@{1}`.